# Youtube API Post a comment on a Video

Tags: android, ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using Youtube API to show video and now i need to Post a comment on YouTube Video. Here is the code for iOS which is working

```
NSString *urlStr = @"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/W_KEuea8eIw/comments";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *xmlString = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"xmlns:yt=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007;\"><content>This is a crazy video</content></entry/>";
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
[request setValue:@"application/atom+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setValue:@"2.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@",kSampleDeveloperKey] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-GData-Key"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",self.auth.accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData*returnData=[ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
NSLog(@"responseData: %@", content);
```

Now I'm trying to POST a comment on android using a HTTP Post request but unable to make a POST URL in android

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId=ffL25JVXbo0&key=AIzaSyAQSINj5dtoLdSNJA3cc6dkziFC2zbbEuk&snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textOriginal=my%20comment
```

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I try it and I successfully posted a comment in the video that you provide.

[image]

Try to use the **Try it part** of this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert) and check if your comment is there in the video.

Take NOTE that change the dropdown button to **Newest first** to view the latest comment in checking the comments in the video.

[image]

Also, it is stated in the documentation of [`CommentThreads: insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert) that you must specify a value for these properties:

- `snippet.channelId`
- `snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textOriginal`

So try to include also the channelId in your request.

Comment: do you have snippet of the request to be passed? I tried this method. went to `https://www.hurl.it/`  then selected POST option. Inside URL `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&key=MyKey`  and in the Body `{"0":{"name":"snippet.channelId","UCfwHP1M0AFSPqTdjzXhV0Zg":""},"1":{"name":"snippet.videoId","PA6oX7YPLWc":""},"2":{"name":"snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textOriginal","Thank You for the Recipe":""}}` But this gave me 401 error. I did not select any authentication method. My assumption is when we use Api key we do not need any authentication.